# How to get one DIV in a maze of DIVs

Tags: javascript, html

i've got this html:

```
  <div id="a">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="c">Stuff</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="b">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="c">Stuff</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The questions is short: How can i get the "c" div which is in the "a" div? Will i still get duplicate id definition? If the html has to be changed, change it... I just need the code that actualy works. :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> The questions is short: How can i get the "c" div wich is in the "a" div?

You have invalid HTML. You cannot have 2 elements in your DOM with the same id. Once you fix your markup and change the id of the second div you could use the [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) function:

```
var cDiv = document.getElementById('c');
```

And here's how you could change your HTML in order to avoid duplicate ids:

```
<div id="a">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="c">Stuff</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="bc">Stuff</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what he said. id is a unique identifier, you cant have 2 with the same value on one page.

Answer (score 0):

The id should be across whole of the page

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is invalid html, this usually works

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var ac = a.getElementById("c");
```

Comment: Ah. I'm sure it doesn't work in IE, and I had an idea it didn't work in FF though I haven't tested it.

Comment: i've just tested it and it works in IE9 and firefox 8. http://jsfiddle.net/qV7MG/

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for taking the trouble. (On this PC I only have Chrome and IE8, and it definitely doesn't work in IE8 - `a.getElementId` is `undefined`. I'm sure it didn't work in older IE either.)